# How to embed or add visual Web part to custom page layout in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to add a visual webpart to custom page layout in sharepoint 2013. But i am getting an error like bellow:

> Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartZone' does not have a
>   public property named 'ACRPS_LatestIssueWebPart'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add properties to the webpart in the webpart zone?
For reference there is a kb article provided by microsoft.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/911715